# Can't install npm packages globally and path fix doesn't work

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

I get a `bash:command not found` even after getting success installing npm packages globally w `npm install -g react-native` or the like.

I followed https://medium.com/@jagatjyoti.1si13cs040/npm-g-install-npm-package-not-working-as-desired-why-why-why-19795abf0b59 verbatim, and tried using `sudo`, however after install I still get the `bash:command not found`

What is wrong here and how can I install global npm packages on my mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the executables such as `react-native`, when installed globally, should be located in `/usr/local/bin`. Try to run `/usr/local/bin/react-native` and if that works, check whether you have `/usr/local/bin` included in your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`);

If you can't find `react-native`, or any other globally installed executable at the above mentioned location, run

```
npm bin -g
```

which will tell you where to look. Once you know the location, repeat the above mentioned steps - try to execute it specifying the full path and check whether the location is included in the `PATH`.

To include an entry in the `PATH`. Go to your home directory and add this entry (line of code)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuser/bin
```

to `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file. If that file doesn't exist, create one (restart terminal afterwards).

Comment: Ok. sorry, when I do npm bin -g I get  /Users/myuser/bin (not in PATH env variable)

Comment: Right. How do I set the PATH env variable exactly?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

This error is because npm is not able to put the globally installed packages on the right path, you can fix it easily by removing `~/.npmrc`, fellow the steps below it should resolve your issue.

**Possible fix**

check if you have anything related to files with prefix in `~/.npmrc`.

1. Open your terminal and enter

   Enter in terminal

   ```
   ~/.npmrc
   ```

   Possible output

   ```
   zsh: permission denied: /Users/{...}/.npmrc
   ```
2. Now remove them with

   Enter in terminal

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.npmrc
   ```

Now you can install any global package and use them

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```

Now that it's removed, npm install -g should put expo in the right place, and everything should Just Work :-)

[Link to original answer](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1954)